# Sound is lower in ubuntu than windows, pulseadio error

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Good Evenning, I would like to know if someone knows how to solve the following problem.

I have two operative systems in my computer, each one in a different disk.

The problem is that when I use ubuntu 20.04, the sound in general is lower than when I use windows which I have no idea why.

I haven looking in internet for ways to solve it, everyone said that the problem is made by pulseaudio.

When I execute it I got the follow:

'''pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ha fallado pa_pid_file_create().'''

Which according to what I read it's a problem, so I tried to solve it using the different ways that I have found now, but I none works.

I have tried uninstalling it, I have tried to getting access to the local file, and another ways but none works.

It's sound fine when I use a speaker, and a little better when I use headphones, but not when is the sound from the machine.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: With "sound is lower", are you referring to the loudness or the frequency?

Comment: I think in this case if Loudness @AndrewMorton

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Does [Volume too quiet at maximum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146766) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, well I have tried now with the [pavucontrol], which I have found until now is that apparently the AudioStream was not at 100%, it was at 70% or 60%.
When I set up it at 100 it of course increase and sound better.
The problem is that only works at the moment, after one video o sound it set again at 60% (I will look how set it permantely).
I also found that for my HDA nvidia, internal speaker and the Audio Internal analog stereo are unplugged which I don't know if it has relevance in this.